# How to set font size in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Hope every one of us had great Christmas so far!

I need a bit of help with my font size in this code:

```
import Pmw
from tkinter import * 
import tkinter.font 

root = Tk()
root.title("Dashboard") 
root.attributes('-zoomed', True)

filename = "SMS.txt"
        
top = Frame(root); top.pack(side='top')
text = Pmw.ScrolledText(top,
       borderframe=5, 
       vscrollmode='dynamic', 
       hscrollmode='dynamic',
       labelpos='n', 
       label_text='Todays Data %s' % filename,
       text_width=120, 
       text_height=35,
       text_wrap='none',
       text_padx=14,
       text_pady=14,
       )
text.pack()
text.insert('end', open(filename,'r').read())

root.mainloop()
```

I want the font size in the text area to be quite big so can be seen on my 3 inch raspberry pi display.

Script Running :
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is documented, and probably mentioned in just about every tkinter tutorial. Have you done any research? Why do you need help from Stackoverflow?

Comment: Why use `Pmw` when `tkinter` has its own `ScrolledText`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following what it says in Pmw's documentation, it seems as though you want to do the following:

```
font_size = 20  # Edit this value here
my_font = Pmw.logicalfont("Fixed", font_size)
text = Pmw.ScrolledText(text_font=my_font)  # Along with the other kwargs you'd need
```

---

### References:

- [Pmw docs](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/refindex.html)
- [Pmw functions](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/PmwFunctions.html) - You'll find `logicalfont()` here, along with what args it takes.
- [`Pmw.ScrolledText()`](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/ScrolledText.html) - It takes a `text_font` kwarg.